# Oozie sub workflow action

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I'm using Oozie for deploying Hadoop workflows. I have a util java action that returns HDFS path based on parameters provided. I'm using capture output property to set the property and retrieve it in subsequent workflow actions.

I would like  to configure this as sub workflow as it is  to be used in different workflows. Is it possible to retrieve action data from a sub workflow in Oozie using EL function ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible using built-in functionality.

You would be able to manually store the data somewhere from the sub-workflow and then manually retrieve it back at the parent workflow, if you were willing to deal with the complexity of it.